# Populating 6th column based on the previous 5 column values

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Please Help me in populating the Marketingsegmentscore based on the values of the 5 columns ActiveStatus    InactiveStatus  LapsedStatus    NoSpecialEventsStatus   SpecialEventsStatus in SSIS

```
if active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 0 marketing_grid_score = 1.
if active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 0 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 2.
if active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 3.
if active= 0 and inactive = 1 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 0 marketing_grid_score = 4.
if active= 0 and inactive = 1 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 0 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 5.
if active= 0 and inactive = 1 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 6.
if active= 0 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 1 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 0 marketing_grid_score = 7.
if active= 0 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 1 and spec_flag = 0 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 8.
if active= 0 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 1 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 9.


    ╔═══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
    ║ AccountNumber ║ ActiveStatus ║ InactiveStatus ║ LapsedStatus ║ NoSpecialEventsStatus ║ SpecialEventsStatus ║ MarketingSegmentScore ║
    ╠═══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
    ║         12345 ║            1 ║              0 ║            0 ║                     1 ║                   1 ║                     0 ║
    ║         45678 ║            0 ║              1 ║            0 ║                     1 ║                   1 ║                     0 ║
    ║         79011 ║            0 ║              0 ║            1 ║                     1 ║                   0 ║                     0 ║
    ║        112344 ║            0 ║              0 ║            1 ║                     1 ║                   0 ║                     0 ║
    ║        145677 ║            1 ║              0 ║            0 ║                     1 ║                   1 ║                     0 ║
    ║        179010 ║            0 ║              0 ║            1 ║                     1 ║                   1 ║                     0 ║
    ╚═══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

- List item

212343  0   0   1   1   1   0

Comment: is there any logic to your requirement ? you question not clear at all.

Comment: if active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 0 marketing_grid_score = 1.
if active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 0 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 2.
if active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 3.
if active= 0 and inactive = 1 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 0 marketing_grid_score = 4.
if active= 0 and inactive = 1 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 0 and nospec_flag = 1 marketing_grid_score = 5.

Comment: Above mentioned is the logic to populate the final column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a CASE ... END. Basically you just want to do something like

```
UPDATE table SET MarketingSegmentScore =
    CASE WHEN active= 1 and inactive = 0 and lapsed = 0 and spec_flag = 1 and nospec_flag = 0 marketing_grid_score = 1 THEN whatever value you want
    CASE WHEN next condition
    etc...
    END
```

Comment: Joseph the OP wants to do this in SSIS, not sure if your answer will be helpful :)

Comment: Hi Joseph thanks for your help it worked copmpletely fine

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be helpful even though you said you were using SSIS. Sometimes it's good to look at alternatives you may not be aware of even though you ask a question on a specific topic. That's why I am not a big fan of dinging people who make contributions to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Derived  Column Task and In the Derived column use the following expression to set the value for `MarketingSegmentScore` column.

```
active== 1 && inactive == 0 && lapsed == 0 && spec_flag == 1 && nospec_flag == 0 ? 1 :(
active== 1 && inactive == 0 && lapsed == 0 && spec_flag == 0 && nospec_flag == 1 ? 2 :(
active== 1 && inactive == 0 && lapsed == 0 && spec_flag == 1 && nospec_flag == 1 ? 3 :(
active== 0 && inactive == 1 && lapsed == 0 && spec_flag == 1 && nospec_flag == 0 ? 4 :(
active== 0 && inactive == 1 && lapsed == 0 && spec_flag == 0 && nospec_flag == 1 ? 5 :(
active== 0 && inactive == 1 && lapsed == 0 && spec_flag == 1 && nospec_flag == 1 ? 6 :(
active== 0 && inactive == 0 && lapsed == 1 && spec_flag == 1 && nospec_flag == 0 ? 7 :(
active== 0 && inactive == 0 && lapsed == 1 && spec_flag == 0 && nospec_flag == 1 ? 8 :(
active== 0 && inactive == 0 && lapsed == 1 && spec_flag == 1 && nospec_flag == 1 ? 9 :0))))))))
```